# jQuery Selectors: how to access an a tag, whose span has a specific class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm messing around with FullCalendar jQuery calendar, and qTips, so that I can display more information about the event upon mouseover.

I've added a summary element to the FullCalendar js, and also my server code.

I then added a new qTip in the eventMouseover method, based on the span class, which works prefectly.  However, if the event stretches over a couple of days, the qTip only works (because it is a span tag), on the text itself, not the entire blue strip.

What I want to do is to assign the qTip to the a tag, and make the a tags display block.

This works currently:

```
        eventMouseover: function(event){
            $('span[class=fc-event-title]').each(function() {
                if( $(this).text() == event.title )
                {
                    $(this).qtip({
                        content: event.summary,
                        style: 
                        { 
                            border: 
                            {
                                width: 1,
                                radius: 5,
                                color: '#6699CC'
                            },
                            width: 200
                        }  
                    });

                }
            });
```

but I can't figure out how to select the a tag where it contains a span with class of fc-event-title.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Anyway you can display:block (or just use a div) for the event instead of a span, that way you don't have to hack around it only activating on the text?

Comment: Hi.  No - the span is created by the FullCalendar plugin, so I dont have direct access to it.  Although I suppose I could try to see what would happen if I change it to use a div instead.  I'll try at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Ivo and Jakob for their very quick responses.

I solved this by changing the way the FullCalendar creates the title on the calendar.  Instead of it using a span, it now uses a div, and being block element, when you hover over a part of the title block which is not text, the qTip still shows.

I'm loving javascript :).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a direct child:

> $(span[class=fc-event-title]:parent)

**Edit:** Never mind, I was wrong. Although I do get it to work with the other answer:

> $(span[class=fc-event-title]).parent()

Comment: Haha, I'm loosing myself here :) I'll re-edit my answer when we get some feedback on what worked for mr Paul.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(span[class=myClass]).parent()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but adding the asterisk didn't make the a tag the center of attraction - it was still the span that was reffered to with the $(this).