# filter out which span to update

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following div collection in my HTML. It's designed to dynamically replicate according to user interaction.

```
 <div class="bill-item">
<!-- Section for a single item -->
<div class="bill-item-img">
<!-- Section for Item pic -->
</div>
<div class="bill-item-description">
<!-- Section for Item description and pricing -->
<div class="bill-item-name">
<p class="bill-item-name-left">Normal Cofee</p><p class="bill-item-name-right">170.00</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="bill-item-price">
<span>170.00 USD</span>
</div>
    <div class="bill-item-amount">
<span>2</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bill-amount-selection">
<!-- Section where the increment & decrement of item amount goes -->
<a class="amount-increase" href="#"></a>
<a class="amount-decrease" href="#"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML Rendered image of the elements.

[image: page]

I've written the following script to increase the bill-item-amount span value.

```
 $(".amount-increase").click(function(){
            x+=1;
            $(".bill-item-amount span").html(x);
        });

        $(".amount-decrease").click(function(){
            if(!x<=0){
                x-=1;
                $(".bill-item-amount span").html(x);
            }
        });
```

This works great but, it updates the value of both the span elements. what I want is to catch the event of the clicked element (which I do now) and increase the span value of the respective span. How can I filter out which span to update using javascript.?

Comment: You can look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601452/jquery-selectors-how-to-access-an-a-tag-whose-span-has-a-specific-class>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should walk the dom tree from the clicked element up until you reach the `.bill-item` element and the go down to the `.bill-item-amount span` node

```
$(".amount-increase").click(function(){
    var $span = $(this).parent().parent().find(".bill-item-amount span");
    var x = $span.html();
    x+=1;
    $span.html(x);
});

$(".amount-decrease").click(function(){
    var $span = $(this).parent().parent().find(".bill-item-amount span");
    var x = $span.html();
    if(!x<=0){
         x-=1;
        $span.html(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the concept from your answer very well! :) Thank you! Although there is a small mistake in your answer. I wanted to increase numeric values but, as your code, it does is do a string concatenation. changing var x = parseInt($span.html()) did the trick! :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like `$(this).parents('.bill-item').find('.bill-item-amount span')` should select the right element.
Inside your callback `this` is assigned to the `eventSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dimal update your code:

```
$(".amount-increase").click(function(){
        x+=1;
        $(".bill-item-amount").html(x);
    });

    $(".amount-decrease").click(function(){
        if(!x<=0){
            x-=1;
            $(".bill-item-amount").html(x);
        }
    });
```

dont add span inside the selector [ it changes entire span values]

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".amount-increase").click(function(){
        x+=1;
        $("use ur increase span id here").html(x); //
    });

    $(".amount-decrease").click(function(){
        if(!x<=0){
            x-=1;
            $("use ur decrease span id here").html(x);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I wanted to go through the DOM hierarchy. That was the trick to capture the right element! :)

Comment: OK man.... But if u have specified an id for each span means it would easier for u to call them in jquery......

Comment: it's not possible in my scenario since I need a dynamic way. I have to design the layout a way that, even if there are 100 elements, JS needs to find the correct element! in your way, I would need to define 100 unique name for each element! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside each function the selector `$(".bill-item-amount span")` will find all the `<span>` amounts in the document. You can *walk the DOM* to find the correct `<span>` using jQuery or plain JavaScript. You seem to be using jQuery functions so my answer also uses jQuery.

The following code combines the two actions into a single function that increases or decreases the amount based on the class name of the `<a>` clicked. I also added a `return false` so that the browser will not follow the *href="#"* on the anchor.

```
$('.bill-amount-selection').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var change = this.className == 'amount-increase' ? 1 : -1
    var $amount = $(this).closest('.bill-item').find('.bill-item-amount span')
    var amount = parseInt($amount.html(), 10) + change
    $amount.html(amount < 0 ? 0 : amount)
    return false
});
```

The use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) means that jQuery v1.7+ is required. I can supply a compatible function with lower jQuery versions if necessary.